# redireccionar a un servlet desde un ajax pasando valores

Tags: java, jquery, html5, ajax, servlets

Hola que tal lo que deseo realizar es redireccionar a una servlet desde un jsp utilizando ajax, ya que tengo que enviar datos que no están en el formulario, pero no se deben de ver en la url colo lo son mascota, edad y el token ya que este ultimo caduca cada cierto tiempo por eso se debe de enviar para saber si todavía es valido y si es así en el servlet hacer uso de los datos escritos por el usuario y los enviados de manera anonima

estees el código en js

```js
 $("#forma").submit(function () {
                var name = $('#nombre').val();
                var ape = $('#apellido').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/TomarValor',
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: {nombre: name, apellido: ape, mascota: yuki, edad:22, token:qwerty123}
                });
            });

este es el código html
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>submit demo</title>
        <style>
            p {
                margin: 0;
                color: blue;
            }
            div,p {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            span {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>datos del usuario</p>
        <form id="forma">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
                <input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="apellido">
                <button type="submit" >enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <span></span>
        
   
    </body>
</html>
```

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "TomarValor", urlPatterns = {"/TomarValor"})
public class TomarValor extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
    String edad = request.getParameter("edad");
    String mascota = request.getParameter("mascota");
    String token=request.getParameter("token");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        if(token.equals("qwerty123")){
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Valores por post jquery</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("nombre " + nombre);
        out.println("apellido " + apellido);
        out.println("edad " + edad);
        out.println("mascota " + mascota);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }else{
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Error</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("El token esta mal");
        out.println("<a href='generarToken'>generar nuevo token</a>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
    String edad = request.getParameter("edad");
    String mascota = request.getParameter("mascota");
    String token=request.getParameter("token");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        if(token.equals("qwerty123")){
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Valores por post jquery</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("nombre " + nombre);
        out.println("apellido " + apellido);
        out.println("edad " + edad);
        out.println("mascota " + mascota);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }else{
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Error</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("El token esta mal");
        out.println("<a href='generarToken'>generar nuevo token</a>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

}
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }//

}

Comment: Cuál es la duda que tenés? En principio si estás haciendo submit de un formulario con POST, los parametros no van en la url e irián igual que como los estás queriendo mandar con ajax, pero por ahi no estoy viendo lo que es tu duda concreta.

Comment: pues que no se abre el servlet con los datos, yo quiero hacer que cuando le de submit al formulario tome los valores escritos por el usuario y ademas adjute los nuevos  y así pase al  servlet "ToarValor", con los datos y si el token en este caso es valido que los muestre y si no genere uno nuevo, pero no pasa nada cuando hago el submit

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo fue utilizado con spring framework. Solo debes ajustar la logica a tus requerimientos. Este realiza la consulta de forma asincrona sin refrezcar el html completamente sino la parte de interes. Ademas consume un servicio tipo RESTful. El Resultado es un JSON que posteriormente es desglozado para rellenar los campos de una tabla dentro del body del html5.

```
function datos1(pagina){
var ajaxRequest;
var base = "https://localhost:8443/BeautySalon/";

//Identificando el tipo de navegador y ajustando la libreria a usar
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
else ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

// Cuando se halla cargado el ajax se activa la funcion
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){ // 4 Peticion finalizada, 200 http ok

        var stringJson = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);          
        var tablaLocales = document.getElementById("localesUsuario");
        var filasTotales = tablaLocales.rows.length;

        // Borrando todo el contenido de la tabla
        for(var fila=1; fila < filasTotales; fila++){               
            tablaLocales.deleteRow(-1); // borrando desde la ultima fila
        }

        // Recorriendo el JSON
        for(var i in stringJson){ // Recorriendo por bloque JSON

            // Datos de interes
            var idLocal = stringJson[i].local.idLocal,
                foto = stringJson[i].local.imagen,
                nombreLocal = stringJson[i].local.empresa,
                personal = stringJson[i].personal,
                direccion = stringJson[i].local.direccion;
            // Estructura Tabla
            var row = tablaLocales.insertRow(-1),
                celdaIdLocal = row.insertCell(0),
                celdaFotoyNombre = row.insertCell(1),
                celdaPersonal = row.insertCell(2),
                celdaDireccion = row.insertCell(3);

                // Agregando informacion
                celdaIdLocal.innerHTML = idLocal;
                celdaFotoyNombre.innerHTML = "<img src=\""+foto+"\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\"/>\n"+
                                  "&nbsp;&nbsp;\n"+
                                  "<span>"+nombreLocal+"</span>";
                celdaPersonal.innerHTML = personal;
                celdaDireccion.innerHTML = direccion;

        }


    }
}

// Creando una peticion GET hacia una URL destino de forma asincrona
ajaxRequest.open("GET",base+"admin/dashboard/recargar/locales?paginaNro="+pagina, true);


// Enviando la peticion
ajaxRequest.send();

   }
```

Comment: Te sugiero realices un ejemplo de acuerdo a lo que pregunta el OP, revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que hay un par de cosas que se necesitan aclarar para que puedas resolver tu pregunta:

1) Si haces submit del formulario, se refresca la página cargando el html que responde el servlet.

2) Si haces la llamada del ajax, el html que devuelve el servlet se recibe en una variable dentro del javascript y debes manipular el DOM para reemplazar el html existente por el recibido (no hay una actualización de la página)

3) Los campos adicionales de mascota, edad, y token, pueden enviarse en el formulario como `<input type="hidden">`, o los campos nombre y apellido pueden enviarse en el ajax como dos atributos en el campo data.

4) Si la elección de enviar el ajax es para que los campos no salgan en la url, estas basando la decisión en una premisa incorrecta. El que los datos vayan en la url o en el body depende del método de la llamada. Es decir que si haces un `POST` ya sea con el formulario o con ajax, los campos viajarán en el body y no en la url. Lo inverso también es válido si usas el método `GET`. En este caso, ya sea con un form o con ajax, los campos se agregan a la URL. (En tu ejemplo no estaba seteado el método, por lo tando defaulteaba a `GET`)

5) En el `<input>` el atributo `name` es el que define el nombre con que el servlet puede encontrar el parámetro. Este atributo faltaba tanto en `nombre` como en `apellido` por lo que el servlet no debería estar puediendo levantar esos datos.

Por como tenés armado el servlet que devuelve html (vs devolver solo datos) me parece que lo que en realidad querés es enviar el formulario con los campos hidden y método `POST`.

```html
<form id="forma" method="POST" action="/TomarValor">
     <div>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido">
        <input type="hidden" id=mascota name="mascota" value="yuki" />
        <input type="hidden" id="edad" name="edad" value="22"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="qwerty123" />
        <button type="submit" >enviar</button>
     </div>
  </form>
```